# Ruby: Why is 'while (p || (p=exns.shift))' not the same as 'while p ||= exns.shift'?

Tags: ruby, language-lawyer

What's wrong here? I don't see how the two fragments can behave differently, yet they do.

Full code, try with one or the other while:

```
class T
  def initialize
    @e=[4,2]
  end
  def shift
    r=@e.shift
    puts "[#{r.inspect}]"
    r
  end
end

exns=T.new

while (p || (p=exns.shift))
#while p ||= exns.shift
  puts "p: #{p.inspect}"
  p -= 1
  p=nil if p<1
  puts "   #{p.inspect}"
  puts "T" if p
end
```

The 'while (p || (p=exns.shift))' never seems to short-circuit for some reason. I'd like to know the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the letter you chose to name your variable - `p` is not like other letters (say `q`), since it is also the name of the Kernel method [`p()`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/p):

```
p
# => nil
q
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `q' for main:Object
```

for that reason, because you did not define a local variable names `p` before the while loop, it is actually declared *only inside the scope of the loop*.

To see how this matters, simply add the following line before the loop:

```
p = nil
```

Now, both options act the same.

Comment: It's `Kernel#p`, actually

Comment: I even noticed that the var wasn't defined beforehand, but didn't connect those dots...thanks. Going to be hilarity in the office.